# How to implement this design using Bootstrap Grid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to implement the below grid structure,

[image: Properly Aligned Required]

I have used the following to achieve this:

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
             <!-- Default panel contents -->
            <div class="panel-heading">
                ....
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                ....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
             <!-- Default panel contents -->
            <div class="panel-heading">
                ....
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                ....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
             <!-- Default panel contents -->
            <div class="panel-heading">
                ....
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                ....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
             <!-- Default panel contents -->
            <div class="panel-heading">
                ....
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                ....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">

         <!-- Default panel contents -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
            ....
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I am facing is that this grid structure is achieved but the all the panels/box are not aligned,

[image: Improper Alignment]

How can I make the Bottom of all Div/Panels Aligned ??

Comment: can the blocks have a fixed height?

Comment: you should include your code in container and row classes.http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Seems to work alright to me: http://www.bootply.com/PZwg4lvHIT

Comment: @Suvojit : Do you want the same layout in small screens too?

Answer (score 1):

You should add Row divs to define the rows

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-8">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
     <!-- Default panel contents -->
     <div class="panel-heading">
      ....
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      ....
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
     <!-- Default panel contents -->
     <div class="panel-heading">
      ....
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      ....
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
     <!-- Default panel contents -->
     <div class="panel-heading">
      ....
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      ....
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
     <!-- Default panel contents -->
     <div class="panel-heading">
      ....
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      ....
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
   <!-- Default panel contents -->
   <div class="panel-heading">
    ....
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
    ....
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

well i using my own css property look the example [Fixed Design](http://jsfiddle.net/ccdiego5/e5rbg5m2/)

Here the code:

```
<style>
.pad1{
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    min-height: 100px;
}
.pad2{
    margin: 2px 2px 2px -130%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    min-height: 204px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: oh sure isn't adaptable :(